# Work efficiently between ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I have not knowledgement about ASP.NET programming, only C# programming (Desktop Apps, not Web-based apps). I have been assigned to a projet which is web-based using ASP.NET. The part of GUI (Web and ASP.NET) is done by another person and I only do the part related to C# programming (not web, lower level) that have to communicate with a SQL database in order to process the events raised from the ASP.NET GUI. So I would like to know which is the best way to work efficiently in this scenario. Is it better that my part C# (Not web) be a DLL and then called from ASP.NET code (by the person who is in charge of ASP.NET coding)? I think it is necessary to define an interface between ASP.NET GUI part and my part. By the way, I think that it is a good practice to use MVC pattern here, but how to isolate the two parts correctly to avoid conflics (as one person implements ASP.NET GUI and I, the lower level C# communication with database)? I do not want to have any kind of problems when integrating the two parts. I highly appreciate suggestions.

Comment: What is actually your question.. ?

Comment: With given scenario I would recommend to use MVC (model-view-controller) pattern. Here you have some more reading: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're responsible for implementing the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).

My suggestion is to create an assembly that contains these repositories classes and your MVC programmer can use them to return information for display, and use those same classes for actual tasks.

Don't go down the route of having "Insert" and "Update" methods in your repositories.  Sit down with whomever has asked you to do this and get a clear indication of what units of work are being done, and with that you'll be able to create methods on your repositories that are clearly defined.

Comment: A lot of thanks. You point me in the right direction.